# File per class approach and module internal classes

Tags: typescript

For readability reasons I have only one class per TypeScript file.

File `TypeScript/Components/MyComponent/A.ts`:

```
namespace MyComponent {
  export class A {...}
```

File `TypeScript/Components/MyComponent/B.ts`:

```
namespace MyComponent {
  export class B {...}
```

Every component folder includes a `tsconfig.json` with `outFile` option so I get one merged js-file `mycomponent.js` per component without having to explicitly reference any classes from the same component.

Everything works but I don't like that the internal module `MyComponent` is transformed to multiple IIFEs:

```
var MyComponent;
(function (MyComponent) {
  ...
  MyComponent.A = A;
})(MyComponent || (MyComponent = {}));

var MyComponent;
(function (MyComponent) {
  ...
  MyComponent.B = B;
})(MyComponent || (MyComponent = {}));
```

Can I tell TypeScript to only generate one IIFE for `MyComponent` similar to how it is done when I define multiple classes inside one module and inside one file? If I generate one js-file based on multiple ts-files shouldn't the compiler see that a module is "reused" and then merging the classes into one module properly?

Also it would be great to have classes that are only visible inside `MyComponent` and not outside. Right now I have to make every class public with `export`, otherwise I get `Cannot find name ...` compile error even within the same module.

I'm using TypeScript 1.7. Also I'm not using any special module stuff. I'm just sending the merged component js-file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I tell TypeScript to only generate one IIFE for MyComponent similar to how it is done when I define multiple classes inside one module and inside one file?

The TypeScript compiler does not offer this optimization at the moment. TypeScript minification is being discussed here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8

Comment: I think doing this as a minification step is the wrong approach for this problem because of those module internal classes I'd like to use.

Comment: You cannot use module internal classes across files at the moment.

Comment: Year ago and still not possible. Terrible.